# Update meson on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS -- force update

Tags: 18.04, apt, updates

Trying to build a package that requires meson to be > 0.47 -- current installed version in /usr/bin is 0.45.

While I can install with pip3 and it does indicate that it successfully installs 0.53.01 - nothing apt install, pip3, etc will upgrade to the new version. And I can't seem to move the new executable either.

What do I need to do to update meson? I've tried removing it and reinstalling, using pip3, etc.

Nothing seems to work -- this is a sticking point on this build. Thanks for any pointers in advance.

Comment: Also I tried this and meson is still listed as installed as an older version -- if anyone can help would be much appreciated:

`sudo -H pip3 install --target=/usr/bin --upgrade meson

Collecting meson
Installing collected packages: meson
Successfully installed meson-0.53.1
$ meson --v
0.45.1
`

Answer (score 6):

After installing using `pip3 install --user meson` you need to reload your `.profile`.

Comment: That worked! Had to remove it first with apt-get like so `sudo apt-get remove meson`

Comment: Sometimes it may be cleaner to simply run the version of meson installed to your python environment, without affecting your systemwide installation. Just use `whereis meson` to locate and run it.

Answer (score 2):

I upgraded `meson` from https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson.git and added it in front of my `$PATH`, but some scripts seem to use a hardcoded path to `/usr/bin/meson`, so that was not enough.

After the upgrade, I had the new version at `~/src/meson/meson.py` which I copied to `~/src/meson/meson` (without the `.py` extension).

Then, what fixed it for me was

```
my_meson=~/src/meson # <-- Adapt to the path of your wanted meson directory

export PATH=$my_meson:$PATH
echo 'export PATH='$my_meson':$PATH' >>~/.bashrc

sudo ln -si $my_meson/meson /usr/bin/meson
```

The essential part is the last line, which replaces the original symlink to point to the new version.

Answer (score 1):

You can try updating your PATH var so that the new version is found first.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/youruser/.local/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

`python3 -m pip install meson` installs the latest version

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/meson /usr/bin/meson` sets up the link